# Some problems with definite articles

Tags: grammar, british-english, articles

> Is there anything good on telly tonight?

Why don't we place an article before "telly"? I think it should be "on the telly".

> He enjoys the beauties of nature in Siberia.

Why do we use "the" before "beauties" and we don't use an article before "nature"?

> Novgorod was the main Russian port for many centuries and was important for Baltic sea trade.

Why don't we use "the" before "Baltic sea"?

> Immediately before this he had served as Chancellor of the Exchequer.

On Wikipedia we can see another variant, "**The Chancellor of the Exchequer**". Why don't we use "the" in this case?

Comment: 1, 2, 3: *telly, nature, trade* are being treated as uncountable (mass) nouns.

Comment: In American English, _on the tube, on TV_. There is no general rule for articles. They are completely idiomatic; that is, any rule fhat requires or forbids article  use only applies to one construction (or one particular word); articles elsewhere follow slightly different (or maybe totally different) rules. Article use and preposition use are the last things people learn in English; like Chinese characters, it simply takes a very long time to encounter all of them in context and work out one's own rules.

Answer (score 2):

1. Plenty of people **do** say "on the telly"
2. Some languages **do** use the article before "nature" – Norwegians are forever going walks "in the nature". 
   Anglophoness just don't, that's all, to us it's a condition not a *place*. (But two can play at this game – the French put an article before names of countries and we don't. Ditto abstractions: why do we not pursue the justice and build the socialism?)
3. Baltic is being used as an adjective not a noun, but see also Peter Shor above on trade; compare "the submarine sank in THE Baltic".
4. Chancellor. Well-spotted that both exist. 
    Best if Peter comes round for another bite, but my ten kopeks would be that without the article, it has an air of being a *title* rather than just a function. In "The Mikado", Pooh-Bah is "Lord High Everything Else", and putting the article there would have suggested that *all* countries had a Lord High Everything Else, not just an imaginary Japan. 
    (All countries have a finance minister, even if only the Brits have this weird name for him, going back to the 12th century.)